# Sentence transformation

Tags: grammar

> He started working for this factory a year ago.

Which sentence has the same meaning?

> He has been working for this factory for a year.

or

> He has worked for this factory for a year.

Comment: Either. The continuous (_has been working_) is more idiomatic for me.

Comment: Also, someone works **at** or **in** a factory, and works **for** a company or organisation, but they don't work *for a factory*.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the tenses of each sentence, they actually all are stating different things and are not alike.

> He started working for this factory a year ago.

This sentence is stating that our undefined subject, "he", started working at a particular factory one year ago. The past tense does not give any information at all to the present, we only know that our undefined subject was working at this particular factory for some time and that he started this employment one year ago.

> He has been working for this factory for a year.

This sentence is stating that our undefined subject has worked at this factory for at least one year and is *also* currently working at the factory. The "has been working" is a form of the present perfect continuous tense, which is used to denote an event that happened in the past and is still ongoing *or* is still applicable to the present.

> He has worked for this factory for a year.

This sentence is stating that our undefined subject worked at this particular factory for at least one year at some point in the past and that this information is probably relevant to the present. The major difference in meaning between this sentence and the prior one is that "working" is the *continuous* tense form of the verb "to work", while "worked" is the *past* tense form of the verb "to work". We can assume that the third sentence is referring to a past event and *not* a continuous event because of the verb tense used, while it is still relevant to the present because of the present perfect tense of "has".